# Getting a file from BitBucket Rest API v2.0

Tags: rest, api, curl, bitbucket

I have a script which grabs a file from GIT using the bitbucket REST API (1.0) however it has recently stopped working. I'm theorizing this may be due to the v1 REST API being depreciated but I'm not sure.

Anyway I am trying to retrieve the file using the new 2.0 REST API but I can't seem to get the syntax right as the request continually fails.

I'm starting out with curl since its easiest to test. This is what I'm trying:

```
curl -u myusername@mydomain.com "https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/MyCompany/myrepo/downloads/Scripts/Environment Setup/test.txt"

Enter host password for user 'myusername@mydomain.com': redacted

{"type": "error", "error": {"message": "Resource not found", "detail": "There is no API hosted at this URL.\n\nFor information about our API's, please refer to the documentation at: https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/"}}
```

Here is the reference documentation I am using: https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Busername%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D/downloads/%7Bfilename%7D

Maybe I am using the wrong function? I'm not sure.

Comment: What happens if you replace the space in that URL with a `%20`?

Comment: That doesn't make a difference (same exact message)

Comment: If I do this: curl --user myuser@mydomain.com:redacted https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/MyCompany/myrepo/refs/branches I get a list of branches. So I know my username is right, my password is right, I can hit the api.bitbucket.com/2.0 URL so I'm not sure if the issue is with the "downloads" feature. Maybe I am using it wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For posterities sake, you don't want to use the following to download an individual file from bitbucket:

https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/MyCompany/myrepo/downloads/path/to/your/file.txt

("Downloads" is to download entire repo files  like a .zip file)

Instead you want to do:

```
curl --user myuser@mydomain.com:password "https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/MyCompany/myrepo/src/master/path/to/file.txt"
```

If you're trying to use Invoke-RestRequest (in powershell) note there are some extra steps. With the old 1.0 API you could do:

```
$cred = Get-Credential

$uri = "https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/MyCompany/$($filepath)"

# Get the files from bitbucket (GIT)
Invoke-RestMethod -Credential $cred -Uri $uri -Proxy $proxyUri -OutFile $destination
```

With the new 2.0 API that no longer works. Powershell's Invoke-RestMethod waits for a 401 response before sending the credentials, and the new 2.0 bitbucket api never provides one, so credentials never get sent causing a 403 forbidden.

To work around that you have to use the following ugly hack to force Invoke-RestMethod to send the credentials immediately in an Authorization header:

```
$cred = Get-Credential


$uri = "https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/MyCompany/$($filepath)"
$username = ($cred.GetNetworkCredential()).username
$password = ($cred.GetNetworkCredential()).password
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $username,$password)))

# Get the files from bitbucket (GIT)
Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Uri $uri -Proxy $proxyUri -OutFile $destination
```

Hopefully that helps someone else out in the future!

Thanks @Jim Redmond for the help.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the PowerShell module [BitbucketServerAutomation](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/BitbucketServerAutomation/1.0.0).  There's not a ton of cmdlets, they do have Get-BBServerFile and Get-BBServerFileContent.  I have found it is well written, very usable and being updated regularly.  The Invoke-BBServerRestMethod cmdlet is available if you need a command it doesn't have.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. As you said it's a nicely written module that provides a lot more than just the ability to retrieve a file: you can create projects, branches, pull requests, enable and disable hooks, etc. It's a nice module.