# Issue in getting authenticated on bitbucket, using python script

Tags: python, automation, bitbucket

I'm trying to get all project list from bit bucket, using username and app password. But getting 401 error.

I'm using atlasian python library for client connection, and below is the code.

```
bitbucket = Bitbucket(url='https://api.bitbucket.org',username="",password="")

data = bitbucket.project_list()

for data in data:
    print(data)
```

Even tried with bitbucket user name and password still same.
Is there any way to generate key or something which can be used all the time not like oauth as it has expiration time.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use App passwords as mentioned [here](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/meta/authentication)

Using an app password
An app password is a substitute password for your user account, when authenticating with Bitbucket:

- your Bitbucket username (not email) which can be found in the [settings](https://bitbucket.org/account/settings/)
- the app password

Comment: tried that as well, still same. what about the base url, will this will work even my repo is private

Comment: you need access tokens : https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/bitbucket/oauth-2/

Comment: default expiry time for that is 7200 right. what if i dont want to change it every time

Comment: what do you mean by change it ?

Comment: default expiry time for access token is 7200 if i use that token in in my script then after expiration i need to change it again right.

Comment: Getting this error : requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/projects

Comment: that's because this is API 2.0 : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53072875/getting-a-file-from-bitbucket-rest-api-v2-0  ,,, also a workspace is needed : https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/workspaces/%7Bworkspace%7D